# How to ignore the minute part in cron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

```js
*/41 * 6-20 ? * * *
```

so I have this cron expression and I want it to send a command every 41 seconds e.g. if it sends a message at `2:00:00` the next message should be sent at `2:00:41` but it also sends a message at `2:01:00` but I don't want it to send a message at `2:01:00` so how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You have */41 in the minutes specifier - that means every 41st minutes.

```
#       .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
#       |       .------------- hour (0 - 23)
#       |       |       .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
#       |       |       |       .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
#       |       |       |       |       .----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)  OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
#       |       |       |       |       |
#       *       *       *       *       *
```

Since cron does not go down to sub-minute resolutions, you will need to find another way(for eg: you can use sleep)

Comment: nice ascii chart

Comment: node-cron have the second part too..

Comment: I really appreciate your words. Thank you

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Haruke-Sensei/f55876b1497e1f15bff8b682e88f2192

Comment: `cron.schedule("*/41 * * * * *", function() {
      console.log("running a task every 41 second");
    });`

Comment: @jeesj `schedule.scheduleJob('*/41 * 6-20 * * *',()=>{    console.log('Ran a command @ ', new Date().toString())})` [code screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/X9tzRyl.png), [result screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/u2zsmMi.png) but you can see that it runs the command at 16:22:00 too

Comment: @HarukeSensei please refer [Scheduling tasks in Node.js using node-cron](https://blog.logrocket.com/task-scheduling-or-cron-jobs-in-node-using-node-cron/).

kindly use given syntax `cron.schedule(cronExpression: string, task: Function, options: Object)`